# Is there a way to set the number of decimal places without setprecision?

Tags: c++

I have a really specific question.
Can I arithmetically get 1.5 from 1.523, in c++ but without using the iomanip library?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want another float/double with the value 1.5 or a string with the characters "1.5"?

Comment: Are you asking how to print a float with only one digit after the decimal point, or are you asking how to round/convert a float to another numerical type that stores a single digit after the decimal point? In the first case, use setprecision, that's what it's for. In the latter case it really depends on your specific use case. Can you provide example code with input and desired output, and give more context for what you are trying to do exactly? (Maybe nitpicky, but `1.523` cannot be represented in a float (or double) in most C++ implementations, so it's not clear what your input actually is.)

Comment: it's called a [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point). It's not a geographical thing so we don't call it a "spot"

Comment: @phuclv The terminology people use around real numbers is frequently appalling, but what the OP is talking about is called a 'decimal place', not the point, which is the '.'.

Comment: @zdan I want a float/double afterwards

Comment: Multiply by 10, then [truncate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc), then divide by 10.  Powers of 10 perform *shifting*.  See also `std::floor` and `std::ceil`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Thanks! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `precision()` directly on the cout, e.g.

`std::cout.precision(2);`

Comment: Which is exactly what `std::cout << std:::setprecision(2)` does internally.

Comment: But, it doesn't require including library.

Comment: @benjaminkljn who said no? You must include `iostream` in order for it to work